# Azure APIM : stuck with identity provider and AD B2C custom domain

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management

**Problem**
We are successfully using our ADB2C tenant as an identity provider for our Azure API management instance.
Several months ago we integrated a B2C custom domain thanks to Azure Front Door. We now want to no more use the xxxx.b2clogin.com endpoint for the authorization endpoints within APIM B2C identity but instead our B2C custom domain.

The problem is that I'm unable to update the authority endpoint with my custom domain url. It always leads to an "Azure Active Directory B2C authority is not valid." error.

**Question**

How can we handle this? We clearly want to use our B2C custom domain in order to benefit from our FrontDoor features, and also to block (at B2C side), in the future, all the signin attempts that will target the b2clogin.com domain.

**Edit**
Seems my question was not so clear! To resume, I'm just trying to update the settings of my ADB2C IDP within the APIM identities blade, in order to use our B2C custom domain instead of the [tenantname].b2clogin.com.
This IDP is already functional for a long time now on the b2clogin domain, we now want to align the APIM with the implementation of the custom ADB2C domain. There is clearly no action to do on our ADB2C app which is already well configured.

In this picture below, we simply tried to change the Authority field from [myb2ctenant].b2clogin.com our custom B2C domain (sample here is mylogin.customdomain.com)

[image]

As far as I remember it was already a mess when we had to switch for login.microsoftonline.com to the b2clogin url :(

Comment: Show us what you are doing and where, what values are you changing? Are you changing them in your App? If so, what kind of App? Or at APIM? Its very vague where the problem actually is.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT question edited, ty

Comment: Looks like you are trying to add AAD B2C as an IdP to the APIM Developer Portal, as per this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad-b2c#configure-identity-provider-for-developer-portal). APIM experts might be able to help. From an AAD B2C perspective, that is the correct Authority URL.

Comment: We already have our AAD B2C tenant as IPD for our APIM since now several years. We just want to change the existing xxxx.b2clogin.com to login.customdomain.com which is our custom domain for our current AAD B2C tenant (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-domain?pivots=b2c-user-flow)

Comment: Seems like APIM dev portal IdP config is limiting the domain name to b2clogin.com... On the surface, it doesn't look possible to add the B2C custom domain name here.

Answer (score 1):

APIM currently has does a validation check for onmicrosoft.com for B2C Login Tenant and .b2clogin.com for B2c Login Authority.  This validation results in the Azure Active Directory B2C authority is not valid if anything but those domain names are used.

Feature still hasn't gotten input as of 4/23.

New releases can be tracked here.
https://github.com/Azure/API-Management/releases

Answer (score 0):

I found a dirty workaround for this as I ran into the same problem recently but it involves two B2C tenants, which means double MAU hits (1 in each tenant).

In APIM you have your main tenant (`maintenant`) using the b2clogin.com domain and a new sign-in/up policy, let's call it `custom-domain-redirect`.

The user journey in `custom-domain-redirect` calls a OIDC technical profile to the second tenant (`b2cproxy`).

The same `custom-domain-redirect` policy is on the `b2cproxy` tenant but the OIDC technical profile points back to `maintenant` on your custom domain and the real sign-up/in policy.

So: APIM >> maintenant.b2clogin.com >> b2cproxy.b2clogin.com >> mylogin.customdomain.com.

It's dirty, but it works. Unfortunately, you do need two tenants, redirecting to the same tenant (even on a different domain) causes a 400 bad request (I guess B2C is checking the tenant ID in the state parameter and rejects it).

```xml
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06"
  PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0"
  TenantId="yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com"
  PolicyId="B2C_1A_force_custom_domain"
  PublicPolicyUri="http://yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_force_custom_domain">
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>

    <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <Domain>customdomain</Domain>
      <DisplayName>Login using custom domain</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="custom-domain-openidconnect">
          <DisplayName>Use Custom Domain</DisplayName>
          <Description>I pity the fool who uses b2clogin.com</Description>
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
          <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
          <Metadata>

            <Item Key="client_id">yourClientID</Item>
            <Item Key="METADATA">https://yourproxytenant.b2clogin.com/yourproxytenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_FORCE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
            <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">openid</Item>
            <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_customDomainHack"/>
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss"  />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" PartnerClaimType="emails"/>    
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin"/>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>  
  </ClaimsProviders>


  <UserJourneys>
  <UserJourney Id="Force-Custom-Domain">
    <OrchestrationSteps>
      <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
        <ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="custom-domain-force" />
        </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      </OrchestrationStep>
      <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
        <ClaimsExchanges>
          <ClaimsExchange Id="custom-domain-force" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="custom-domain-openidconnect" />
        </ClaimsExchanges>
      </OrchestrationStep>
  
      <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="SendClaims"
        CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
    </OrchestrationSteps>
    <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
  </UserJourney>
</UserJourneys>
  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="Force-Custom-Domain" />

    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">      
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" PartnerClaimType="emails" />    
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```